# Flutter web font size debug vs release mode

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

When I run the exact same code in Flutter debug mode vs release mode I get that the fonts in release mode are smaller.

I use Roboto Google font from https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts

Any idea what is happening or how to debug this?

Comment: how many small font? show me the image

Answer (score -1):

Use media query as bellow:

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
builder: (context, child) {
final mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
final scale = mediaQueryData.textScaleFactor.clamp(1.01, 1.1);
return MediaQuery(
data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: scale),
child: child!);
});
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).